# How Can I Add/Remove a New Row Which Shows the Details of its Parent Row When I Click Same Parent Row?

Tags: jquery

I have a table which creates dynamically. I would like to get the more details when I click on the More (+) button of a particular row.

As per my requirement, I can add a new row by using the below code. But the issue is, I should remove the new row when I click Hide (-). That is not working

```
$('#tableEmpList').delegate('a.addRow', 'click', function () {   
var _Result="<tr><td>New Row</td></tr>"            
var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the parent row of the clicked button
 $(_Result).insertAfter(row);     
}
```

When I use

```
$(_Result).Remove(row);
```

which only removes the same parent row not the new child row

Comment: You've capitalized `remove` which makes it nonexistent

Comment: @matt I need to remove the newly added row not the same one

Comment: I was pointing out your typo unless you've defined your own `Remove` method. Also, `delegate` is deprecated in favour of `on` in jQuery 3.0+. I think your issue is that `_Result is not a CSS selector so won't work when creating a jQuery object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can try this code here.**

Description: when a user click the add row button or element then the find the parent tr and it's after adding an element. and when user click the remove button then the find parent tr and remove it.

```js
$('#tableEmpList').on('click', 'a.addRow', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var _Result="<tr><td>New Row</td></tr>";
  $(this).parents('tr').after(_Result);
  $(this).text('(-)').removeClass('addRow').addClass('removeRow');
});
$('#tableEmpList').on('click', 'a.removeRow', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('tr').next('tr').remove();
  $(this).text('(+)').addClass('addRow').removeClass('removeRow');
});
```

```css
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableEmpList">
 <tr>
  <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magn
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <a href="#" class="addRow">(+)</a></p></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magn
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <a href="#" class="addRow">(+)</a></p></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magn
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <a href="#" class="addRow">(+)</a></p></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. But my requirement is not like this . When i click addRow a new row is appearing its OK . I would like to remove the newly created row (New row ) when i click on removeRow of the previous row . Which means when click Show More (+) a new row should appear and when click Hide(-) the newly row should remove not the main row

Comment: when you click the (+) then it's an instant change to  (-) and append a item after this. and when you click the minus (-) then the change (-) plus and remove new create or next new item??

Comment: @Jks I am improv my answer please see again maybe it solves your problem

Comment: @ Md.Abu Sayed Thank you . Now its Working fine .  Theses is the code that is missed ($(this).parents('tr').next('tr').remove();) Thanks a lot